# C++ multithreading interruptions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

As you can see in the main function I've created a group of threads that execute the exact same function yet with different parameters. The function simply prints out vector's values. Now the problem is that these threads interfere with one another. What I mean is that one thread does not finish printing (cout) before another starts, and it goes like sdkljasjdkljsad. I want some sort of chaotic order, such as, for example:

```
Thread 1 Vector[0]
Thread 2 Vector[0]
Thread 1 Vector[1]
Thread 3 Vector[0]
Thread 4 Vector[0]
Thread 2 Vector[1]
```

Rather than:

```
Thread 1 Thread 2 Vector[0] Vector[0]
Thread 2 Vector[1]
Thread 1 Thread 4 Vector[1] Thread 3 Vector[0] Vector[1]
```

How can I solve this problem? P.S. Data file is simply a list of player names, weight and bench-press per line. Transforming these to strings and placing in a vector (yeah, sounds dumb, but I'm just fulfilling a task).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>


using namespace std;

 vector<string> Kategorijos;
 vector< vector<string> > Zaidejai;
 ifstream duom("duom.txt");

 string precision(double a) {
     ostringstream out;
     out << setprecision(6) << a;
     return out.str();
 }

void read() {
    string tempKat;
    int tempZaidSk;
    vector<string> tempZaid;

    string vardas;
    int svoris;
    double pakeltasSvoris;
    while (duom >> tempKat >> tempZaidSk) {

        Kategorijos.push_back(tempKat);
        for (int i = 0; i < tempZaidSk; i++) {

            duom >> vardas >> svoris >> pakeltasSvoris;
            tempZaid.push_back(vardas + " " + to_string(svoris) + " " + precision(pakeltasSvoris));
        }
        Zaidejai.push_back(tempZaid);
        tempZaid.clear();
    }
    duom.close();
}


void writethreads(int a) {
    int pNr = a+1;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)Zaidejai[a].size(); i++) {
        cout << endl << "Proceso nr: " << pNr << " " << i << ": " << Zaidejai[a][i] ;
    }
}

void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)Kategorijos.size(); i++) {
        cout << "***   " << Kategorijos[i] << "   ***" << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)Zaidejai[i].size();  j++) {
            cout << j+1<<") "<< Zaidejai[i][j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
}

int main()
{   
    read();
    print();

    boost::thread_group threads
        ;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)Kategorijos.size(); i++) {

        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(writethreads, i));

    }

    threads.join_all();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I must use threads as well as the console, those are requirements of the task. I've done the same thing with Java, the only difference is that I've created 5 separate threads one after another, and it worked perfectly. However, this is kind of dependent on the situation, since I knew that there were 5 blocks of data in the data file. With c++ I want to make sure that the data file could be changed without touching the code, which is why I'm using the for loop and a thread group.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the problem of thread synchronization! When only one thread can use a resource at a time, the lock you use to control that resource is a mutex. You can also store the data for one thread to output at the end, or you can have the threads synch up at a barrier.

Comment: Had a typo there.  Hope the people who down voted will remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronise them, the console writes, with an appropriate mutex. But in this case, with the console output, maybe don't use threads at all. Else send the printing to a dedicated thread that deals with it.

The alternative to using the usual `cout` overloaded `operator <<` is to **write the content to a local buffer or `stringsteam` (including the new line)  and then, with a single function call, write that to the console**. The single function call will assist in the console writer only writing one buffer's contents at a time.

Comment: "write content to a local buffer and forward it in one call" is the best solution.  Let the OS take care of the locking.